# Getting the bounding box of a sphere

Tags: geometry, aabb, sphere

I have a sphere with values `center,radius` and I need to convert the sphere to a bounding box with values `min,max`.

How do I convert a sphere into a bounding box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the bounding box of a sphere is pretty trivial given the simplicity of sphere geometry.

Let's assume we have the radius of the sphere defined as a scalar (float or integer) value \$r\$, and the centre of the sphere defined as a vector \$\overrightarrow c\$ like this:

$$
\overrightarrow c = \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can calculate the outer bound coordinate vectors \$\overrightarrow{min}\$ and \$\overrightarrow{max}\$ by doing the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow{min} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
c_x - r \\
c_y - r \\
c_z - r
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\\
\overrightarrow{max} &=
\begin{pmatrix}
c_x + r \\
c_y + r \\
c_z + r
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

In code, that means:

```cs
// given
Vector3 center = new Vector3(10, 20, 30);
int radius = 5;

// then
Vector3 boundingBoxMin = new Vector3(
    center.x - radius,
    center.y - radius,
    center.z - radius
);
Vector3 boundingBoxMax = new Vector3(
    center.x + radius,
    center.y + radius,
    center.z + radius
);
```

If we'd prefer, another way to calculate this same thing is to define a vector \$\overrightarrow {r_{\text{offset}}}\$ for doing that addition, which simply represents the offset from the center to a corner of the bounding box:

$$
\text{given} \;
\overrightarrow c = \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix}
\; \text{and} \;
\overrightarrow {r_{\text{offset}}} =
\begin{pmatrix}
r \\
r \\
r
\end{pmatrix},
\\
\begin{align}
\overrightarrow {min} &= \overrightarrow c - \overrightarrow {r_{\text{offset}}} \\
\overrightarrow {max} &= \overrightarrow c + \overrightarrow {r_{\text{offset}}}
\end{align}
$$

```cs
// given
Vector3 center = new Vector3(10, 20, 30);
int radius = 5;
Vector3 radiusOffset = new Vector3(radius, radius, radius);

// then
Vector3 boundingBoxMin = center - radiusOffset;
Vector3 boundingBoxMax = center + radiusOffset;
```

## Handling the 2D case

For the 2D case, calculating the rectangular bounding box of a circle, we omit the Z values like normal: \$\overrightarrow c\$, \$\overrightarrow{r_{\text{offset}}}\$ (if you're using that), \$\overrightarrow{max}\$, and \$\overrightarrow{min}\$ will just be 2D vectors and we'll just do only the x and y calculations.

## Diagram!

The following diagram of the 2D scenario might help visualise what's going on here:

[image]

---

One's first instinct might be to calculate a hypotenuse using the Pythagorean theorem (\$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\$) and use that as the magnitude of a vector \$\vec h\$, but that's more computationally expensive than necessary: \$\overrightarrow{r_{\text{offset}}}\$ will give us the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that helped me.

```
min = (center.x - radius, center.y - radius, center.z - radius);
max = (center.x + radius, center.y + radius, center.z + radius);
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: What does vector - scalar mean?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77  Sorry for the confusion. I edited the post

Comment: You box is contained within the sphere. If you want the bounding box that contains the sphere you need to multiply your radius by 1 / .707 or basically use Pythagoras theorem to get the correct sized bounding box. Hope that helps. Sin of 45 degrees basically.

Comment: @ErnieDingo so I create a variable which contains `1 / .7071` and then multiply it by the radius before performing the code above

Comment: @ErnieDingo This does give a box that contains the sphere.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 than just out of interest, how do you get a box that is inside the sphere

Comment: first point: `center - (radius, radius, radius) * sqrt(1/3)`, last point: `center + (radius, radius, radius) * sqrt(1/3)`.

Comment: That produces a box contained in the sphere